# How to generate a square waveform for qwt oscillocope example?

Tags: c++, qt, waveform, qwt

the example  of qwt oscillocope generate a sinus waveform, for my project   I would like to generate a Square or cosinus  wave.
 I tried to find out where the sinus wave is generated , I did'nt find.
 any help will be appreciated 
thx

Comment: Are you asking how to generate a square wave? or where in your code to do so?

Comment: I'm now asking how to generate a square wave or triangular signal. when I try x=sgn(sin(x/period *2*M_Pi) , its doesn't works

Comment: I will post an answer about a square wave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate a 'Mathmatical square wave" meaning non band-limited square wave use the following code:

```
double value = sin(x / period * 2.0 * M_PI)>=0.0 ? 1.0:-1.0;
```

This will give you a wave that would theoretically be the pure analog square wave. As I mentioned above this wave will be non band limited in that it is not going to sound correct because of aliasing. But if you are just using it for a oscilloscope that does not have audio output it will look correct.

Let Me know if this helps.

EDIT: 
For saw...

```
const double Sample_Rate = 44100.0;
typedef struct Saw_Data{
    double _phasor = 0.0;
    double _tolerance = 1.0;
}Saw_Data;

double _DSP::Saw_Wave(double* _frequency,_DSP::Saw_Data* _data){
    double _val = _data->_phasor;
    _data->_phasor += 2.0 * (1.0/(Sample_Rate/ *_frequency));
    if (_data->_phasor > _data->_tolerance) {
        _data->_phasor-=2.0;
    }
    return _val ;
}
```

This is the code i use for a "Mathematical" non band limited saw wave.
Lemme know if you need me to explain it.

Comment: Thanks Alex , the code Helps me , perhaps you also know the code to generate a 'mathematical triangular wave'? and I also want to  modify the code to get  two chanels  so that in chanel 1 I have sinus wave and chanel 2 square wave ,finily  my intention now is also to real time analysis. I  capture a signal from  my computer microphone  with Qtaudio  and show the signal on oscillocope. could you please give me some advice ? thank you

Comment: @user2932518 I actually don't know how to do a triangle wave properly but i can give you a mathematical saw wave if you would like?

Comment: @user2932518 added the saw to my answer

Comment: @user2932518 If my answer was Helpful you can click the "Accept" Button for the answer.(The Check Mark if you don't know)

Answer (score 0):

Searching the oscilloscope directory for the string "sin" reveals that the sin wave is generated in `samplingthread.cpp`. Here is the relevant method:

```
double SamplingThread::value( double timeStamp ) const
{
    const double period = 1.0 / d_frequency;

    const double x = ::fmod( timeStamp, period );
    const double v = d_amplitude * qFastSin( x / period * 2 * M_PI );

    return v;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot , I'm now asking how to generate a square wave or triangular signal. when I try x=sgn(sin(x/period *2*M_Pi) , its doesn't works